# iPhone: how do i redraw subviews while pinch zooming a uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, zooming, subview

I am developing an iPhone app that places multiple custom UIViews as subviews in a UIScrollView.  The subviews are placed on top of each other as transparent views as each view has its own drawing routines that traces parts of the base view.  The base view is a UIImageView that is typically a large image that I want the user to be able to pan and zoom in and out of.

The problem I am having is that when I zoom in and out of my UIScrollView, the subviews do not redraw themselves while the user is zooming. I can reposition and scale the subviews properly once the zoom is completed, but the user experience is less than desirable.  I have not been able to find a way to either hide or redraw the subviews as the zoom is taking place to scale the subviews along with the ImageView.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Here is the code that I have implemented:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {

 for (UIView *view in subViews)
 {
  [view updateView:scale];
 }
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *) scrollView {
 return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Make a UIView that contains the image, as well as all the other subviews, and in the viewForZoomingInScrollView method, return that parent view. All the subviews will be scaled while you zoom, haven't tested to see how well this works with text and complex views, just tried with rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

In >=3.2 there is now:
 - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

So some day in the future this will be the sensible solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

The `imageView` that you are returning from `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` will be resized as the view zooms.  You could implement `setFrame:` or the more standard `layoutSubviews` in that view to do your updating.  The `contentSize` of the scroll view is also updated continually during zooming, so you could implement `setContentSize:` in a custom scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a **proper** way to implement it, but I have a **work-around** for you:

Since the `viewForZoomingInScrollView` is called right before the zooming and `scrollViewDidEndZooming` - right after, you could use the `viewForZoomingInScrollView` to call a method in a separate thread. That method will check the `zoomScale` of your `UIScrollView` each 100 milliseconds (or any other period that would look good) and will make all the needed changes. In `scrollViewDidEndZooming` you will stop the execution of the new method.

Comment: I tried this with a NSTimer instead of a thread, which I think is achieving the same thing.  However, the performance is really bad in the simulator and makes the experience even worse. I think i'll just try and hide the subviews to see if that is a better experience.

Perhaps I need to rethink how I'm designing the subviews and maybe just create a single view that handles all the rendering and detection of touch events.